# Problems installing Bazzar on Debian 10.6

Tags: python

I am trying to install Bazaar on Debian 10.6, but cloning the central repository (from the course server) to my local machine. I get the following error:

> bzr: ERROR: Unsupported protocol for url "`sftp: //<User>@<Ip Server>/home/<user>/public/trunk`": Unable to import paramiko (required for sftp support): No module named paramiko.

Answer (score 1):

Paramiko is a python package that is used for SSH connections.
I guess clone command is trying to make an SSH connection and because Paramiko is not installed you get an Error.

Try to make pip install paramiko and then make the clone again (: